# $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$. If $f(0) = 1$ and $|f '(x)| \leq 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, prove that $|f(x)| \leq |x| + 1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have tried using the definition of differentiable such that the $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$ exists for each $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta>0$ s.t. $\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}<\epsilon$, but I cannot seem to figure out the steps necessary to reach the final conclusion that $|f(x)|<|x|+1$.

I know I let $\epsilon>0$ and $\delta>0$,

Comment: Use the fundamental theorem of calculus

Comment: Mean Value Theorem

Answer (score 3):

First, notice that you can always write $f(x) = f(a) + \int_a^x f'(x)$. If you want to prove this separately, it follows immediately from the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Setting $a = 0$ in the above equation, taking its absolute value, using the triangle inequality and remembering that $| \int f(x)dx | \leq  \int |f(x)|dx$ should get you there.

Comment: Can you show me how to use the triangle inequality here?

Comment: The triangle inequality (at least, the one I know under the name of triangle inequality) states that $|a+b| \leq |a| + |b|$, so we have $ |f(x)| = |f(a) + \int_a^x f'(x)dx| \leq |f(a)| + |\int_a^x f'(x)dx|$